# how to build node based dockerized jenkins-slave that can run the node base project through Jenkins master

Tags: linux, docker, jenkins

I have successfully enabled the Docker API which I can able to connect from the Jenkins. And Now I'm trying to create docker slave agent that can dynamically create and want to create 100 active docker slave agent that can immediately pick the jobs from queue and execute.

I just trying to create a node base docker image which can be act as slave agent and the image file look like below:

**Image Context:**

```
FROM node:15.12.0-alpine3.10
RUN mkdir -p /home/achu/nodeSlave
CMD ["node", "npm --version"]
```

**Output:**

```
[ArrchanaMohan@devops-monitoring-achu ~]$ sudo docker build -t docker-slave-nodes:1.0 .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  7.368GB
```

The GB count is keep increasing and I don't see image is build success message. I'm very new to the docker world, and I'm not sure whether I'm doing right things.

Can someone please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Updated:
Problem Image:

[image]

Comment: You need to start 100 docker containers and run tests? each container needs to run lets say a specific test?

Comment: Yes...That's true.. I have a job which is parameterized. User may trigger the same job with different parameters. When there is a job in build state and other request for the same job going to pending state. I just want the docker should pick the job in pending queue for the same job and needs to run...

Comment: Its like, one container per one unit test?

Comment: Yeah.. I want to know is that possible to each build in the same Job picked up by different docker slave and run them parallelly. Currently I can see each job can run independently by dynamic docker slave. But When I tried to build multiple build in the same job it ran only one at a time and other one moving to pending queue.

Comment: Added problem image in the main question.

Comment: You better to ask this from Jenkins community. https://www.jenkins.io/chat/

Answer (score 1):

You need to use slave image and install node on it.

Here is the one of them;

```
FROM openshift/jenkins-slave-base-centos7:v3.11
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the slave details..!